# Windows + iTunes - Ability to script an auto start playlist?

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, script, itunes

I have a whole home audio system and one of my input devices is a basic headless windows machine. This OS has iTunes on it with a shared network drive that points to my music collection. I have a playlist created within iTunes that I play on one of the inputs that can be selected in any room of the house.

The problem I run into is any time I need to run updates on the machine or iTunes crashed for some reason etc, I had to remote back in and start iTunes and the playlist again.

Are there any ways that I can not only open iTunes from command line but also begin a "shuffle" of the specific playlist I have created?

I can't see anything built into iTunes to do this and assume it would be easy to do on a Mac but I am a little lost on if iTunes even exposes these types of command arguments on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to partially use iTunes from Windows using Powershell - Here's how:

Config:

```
OS: Windows 10 - 64 bits
iTunes version: 12.7
Powershell version: 5.1
```

In Powershell:

```
# Inspired by 
# - https://gist.github.com/rkumar/503162 
# - http://samsoft.org.uk/iTunes/scripts.asp

# Search for iTunes COM object
Get-CimInstance Win32_COMSetting | Select-Object ProgId, Caption | Where-Object Caption -ILike "*itunes*"
# Initializing itunes
$itunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application

# list methods and properties
$itunes | Get-Member
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist | Get-Member
$itunes.LibraryPlaylist | Get-Member
$itunes.CurrentTrack | Get-Member

# commands
$itunes.Play()
$itunes.NextTrack()
$itunes.PreviousTrack()
$itunes.PlayPause()
$itunes.Resume()
$itunes.Stop()

# changing properties
$itunes.SoundVolume = 50 # sound volume to 50%
$itunes.Mute = 0 # mute
$itunes.Mute = 1 # unmute
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.Shuffle = 0 # shuffle off
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.Shuffle = 1 # shuffle on
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.SongRepeat = 0 # repeat none
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.SongRepeat = 1 # repeat one
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.SongRepeat = 2 # repeat all

$itunes.CurrentTrack.Rating = 80 # 100 = 5 stars, 80 = 4 stars, 60 = 3 stars, 40 = 2 stars, 20 = 1 star
$itunes.CurrentTrack.AlbumRating = 80

# Retrieve values
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.Name
$itunes.CurrentPlaylist.Index

# List available playlists
$itunes.Sources.Item(1).Playlists

# Select playlist and start playing
$playlists = $itunes.Sources.Item(1).Playlists
$selPlaylist = $playlists.ItemByName("Name of your playlist")
If ($selPlaylist -ne $null) { $selPlaylist.Reveal(); $selPlaylist.PlayFirstTrack() }
```

More info can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142855/is-it-possible-to-launch-and-use-itunes-with-the-command-line-on-windows